# To be prepared to send media

Tags: media, sip, send, rfc

> Once the offerer has sent the offer, it MUST be prepared to receive media for any recvonly streams described by that offer.  It MUST be prepared to send and receive media for any sendrecv streams in the offer, and send media for any sendonly streams in the offer..

(cit. RFC 3264 An Offer/Answer Model with the Session Description Protocol (SDP), chapter 5.1 Generating the Initial Offer > Unicast streams, last paragraph)

Does term "to be prepared to send media" mean also sending empty RTP-packets without payload inside?

Answer (score 0):

The text you quote from RFC3264 is truncated:

> Once the offerer has sent the offer, it MUST be prepared to receive
>      media for any recvonly streams described by that offer.  It MUST be
>      prepared to send and receive media for any sendrecv streams in the
>      offer, and send media for any sendonly streams in the offer (of
>      course, it cannot actually send until the peer provides an answer
>      with the needed address and port information).  In the case of RTP,
>      even though it may receive media before the answer arrives, it will
>      not be able to send RTCP receiver reports until the answer arrives.

As written: **it cannot actually send until the peer provides an answer**.

I assume that *being prepared to send* refer to the fact that you should
allocate every codecs and socket. Even for a sendonly stream, you may receive
data on the media socket: for example STUN requests, DTLS packets... and
some of this may come before you receive the *SDP answer*. If the socket is
not ready to receive, the OS will probably send ICMP port unreachable which
for example, may introduce delay in setup.

I'm not aware of the existence of *empty RTP packet*. (I've seen some in the
past, but this is not defined by any rfc, as far as I know!)

EDIT: While you will never send RTP packets on the media stream, you SHOULD be able to send STUN (ICE) or DTLS (encryption negociation) packets **BEFORE** you receive the **SDP answer**. Conclusion: You will probably not send media (RTP), but you need to be prepared and handle datas received on the media stream, and **send** answers to STUN, DTLS...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know entire text well. It was truncated because remaining part is out of significance for question asked. RFC text and this Question addresses sending media stream packets and be prepared to send - so context wherein it is made. It can be only after answer to offer. STUN, DTLS - are media streams really involved in those protocols dialogs? Question addresses merely the plane of media streams. Not the control plane.

Comment: STUN (when ICE is used) and DTLS (when encryption is used) are both data packets being sent on media streams. The ICMP issue I'm talking about is also on the media stream. So in practice, you may SEND STUN or DTLS packets on the media stream BEFORE you receive the answer. (Editing the answer to make it clear.)

Comment: Is not SIP-client layer currying out STUN procedures for SIP-layer and for media streams, so that RTP does not need to do that on its own?.

Comment: RFC 3489 (STUN) mentions TCP and UDP ports as ports used for STUN. I wonder if RTP media streams also involve these protocols.

Comment: When speaking about STUN, I'm only talking about ICE (rfc5245) which is using STUN on the media stream. I'm not at all speaking of usage of STUN on SIP layers!

Comment: If RFC under this Question does not refer to ICE (STUN) standard at the point this Question has the focus on I am not sure the above-SIP-layers' behaviour is an objective of quoted RFC text. Thus I still have the impression quoted RFC text addresses merely actual media, streams of RTP packets.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answers and comments: I'm ONLY talking about media streams socket and data exchanged on media streams... You seems to assume that STUN and DTLS refers to SIP layer: this is wrong. It refers ONLY to media streams layer. STUN and DTLS are exchanged on the RTP socket. I hope I made it clear enough.

Comment: "I think you misunderstood my answers and comments" that might well be. Your answer and comments seem to uncover further aspects and points which I can't find in quoted RFC text nor in its direct context.

Comment: Isn't it that way that all UAS' placed behind NAT need to be reachable by UAC's outside NAT and for this SIP or its user also uses STUN & Co.? If yes it looks like SIP or its user is the first instance where STUN is needed (from time perspective). First UAs talk to each other, then media sessions are established. Even in case of early media the media connections follow UAs interactions.

Comment: In my understanding it is SIP who is mastering in VoIP, not media streams or RTP traffic. Media streams thus RTP traffic are result of UAs handshaking. Thus SIP appears to be first one who needs STUN.

Comment: STUN is a tool for protocols. It is used on the SIP layer (as you said, mainly for NAT). It is also used on the media layer (see rfc5245). Those usages are independant of each other. They have different purpose. In my answer (and in my comments), I was only refering to usage of STUN in RTP layer.

Comment: How to see RFC's text quoted at beginning of this Q addresses also STUN, DTLS and os (all but plain media traffic) on media?